# Displaying normalized data in the react UI component

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

Let' say we have normalized object like this one in redux store.

```
{
entities: {
  plans: {
    1: {title: 'A', exercises: [1, 2, 3]},
    2: {title: 'B', exercises: [5, 6]}
  },
  exercises: {
    1: {title: 'exe1'},
    2: {title: 'exe2'},
    3: {title: 'exe3'}
    5: {title: 'exe5'}
    6: {title: 'exe6'}
 }
},
currentPlans: [1, 2]
}
```

I want to display for each plan exercise details in the UI component. Something like.

```
plan 1
title A
  exercises
   exercise 1
   title: 'exe1'
   exercise 2
   title: 'exe2'
   ..........
plan 2
title B
 exercises
  exercise 5
  title: 'exe5'
  ........
```

Do I have to denormalize again ? How do I transform data and where ? Do I use connectStateToProps to do something like

```
 plans: some mapping function that will create nested plans->exercise array
```

or is there another way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you have to denormalize before displaying. For example if you have list of active users stored as denormalized list of user ids, you have to map through those and for each fetch respective object from the state tree.

Yes, probably do this in mapStateToProps.

Sort-of recommended approach is to use a function of (state) => data that will read whatever is needed from state and form a final structure that will be provided to your component.

It's common to use https://github.com/reactjs/reselect for this purpose as it will also memoize output of your selectors for better performance. Note that just like most things in redux, it isn't magic, and you can absolutely go without it. Especially if you're just toying with the framework for now.

Comment: That makes sense. I like the suggestion related to memoization and the reselect library. Did not know about it..Anyway, thanks for your help understanding this process.